# Subtracting the size of a pointer from the size of an address

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof, size-t

What do these address-based distances mean?

```
long dist1 = (size_t)&addr6 - (size_t)p;
long dist2 = (size_t)&local - (size_t)p;
long dist3 = (size_t)&foo - (size_t)p;
```

For reference — `addr6` is a global `int`, `local` is a local `int`, `foo` is a function and `p` is a `void *p` (void pointer).

Comment: There isn't an awful lot of meaning there.  It isn't guaranteed that the difference between two `size_t` values fits in a `long`, for starters.  You might do better with `uintpr_t` and `intptr_t` — if they exist.  Since you've not shown how `p` is initialized, there's no useful answer we can give.  [The standard says](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p9) you can take the difference between pointers to elements of the same array, or one beyond the end of the array.  After that, all bets are off; the standard says "undefined behaviour".

Comment: `size_t` is the appropriate type for the difference between pointers. It's not appropriate for converting a pointer to an integer. And converting between pointers and integers is implementation-dependent.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffer:Its only a part of the code, i can send it all if it helps, I am a student and I can't figure out any meaning to these values

Comment: @Barmar: the difference is formally a `prtdiff_t`, which is a signed quantity, unlike `size_t`.

Comment: @EilonBen-Ishay Whatever the context, it's very implementation-dependent.

Comment: The title of the question doesn't seem to be related at all. You're not getting the size of anything, and there's not really a difference between a pointer and an address (a pointer is a datatype that contains an address).

Comment: Will it help if I send the entire code?

Comment: The only sense I can make is that this is trying to determine how far apart in memory the stack, heap, and code sections are.

Comment: Send only what's relevant. We don't need things like argument processing, user input, output, etc.

Comment: @Barmar: that was my first instict too, thou I wasn't sure what do it get from (size_t)&address

Comment: `(size_t)&variable` yields an unsigned integer that is some sort of approximation to the virtual address where the variable is stored — often a very good approximation to the virtual address. The difference between two unsigned integers is another unsigned integer (another `size_t` value), which is then coerced into a `long` in your code.